# Mysql divide multiple column with 2 statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to divide multiple column with 2 statements  as the following:

```
TBL1
NAME  VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
A     2    3      3

TBL2
NAME  VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
B     2    3      3
```

ERROR SCRIPT

```
select (select * from tbl1)/(select * from TBL2) as result

Result that i need as the following:

VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
2/2  3/3  3/3
```

Comment: Isn't there any common value between these two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a `ON` clause but not sure what it should be

```
SELECT t1.VAL1/t2.VAL1, t1.VAL2/t2.VAL2, t1.VAL3/t2.VAL3, 
FROM TBL1 t1, TBL2 t2
```

Comment: why do you need an on? this join simply joins each two rows 'blindly', this solution is ok, you've beaten me to it ;)

Comment: @Ron.B.I: Thanks. But as I guess, these query produce more than one row where if there is a common column and I can append an ON then it should be one row only.

Comment: @JamDara: as I comment on question, isn't there any common column ? if you provide me this, then it can be corrected

Comment: @JamDara - The only issue with this solution is that does not make the intent clear. Did they simply not know the proper syntax for a cross join? Did the developer forget a Where clause? Did they intend to create a cartesian product? I really wish that all the database vendors would stop supporting the comma-delimited syntax for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that I can come up with is

```
SET @COUNTER1 = 0;
SET @COUNTER2 = 0;
SELECT T1.VAL1 / T2.VAL1,
       T1.VAL2 / T2.VAL2,
       T1.VAL3 / T2.VAL3
FROM       (SELECT *, (@COUNTER1 := @COUNTER1 + 1) AS id FROM TBL1) AS T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, (@COUNTER2 := @COUNTER2 + 1) AS id FROM TBL2) AS T2
ON         T1.id = T2.id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select Tbl1.Val1 / Tbl2.Val1 As Val1
    , Tbl1.Val2 / Tbl2.Val2 As Val2
    , Tbl1.Val3 / Tbl2.Val3 As Val3
From Tbl1
    Cross Join Tbl2
```

Of course, this probaly isn't what you want. Firstly, there is nothing that correlates the rows in Table 1 with the rows in Table 2. I.e., if both tables have three rows each, the result will have nine rows. In short, you will get a Cartesian product between the two tables. Second, there is no logic to deal with dividing by zero errors. Should those values simply be set to zero? Should they be null?

[MySQL Join Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). (Yes MySQL supports the ISO/ANSI standard Cross Join syntax).

[SQL Fiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6f39/1)

#### Edit

If what are trying to do is to concatenate the values into a string expression of `#/#`, then you need to use the `Concat` function:

```
Select Concat(Tbl1.Val1,'/',Tbl2.Val1) As Val1
  , Concat(Tbl1.Val2,'/',Tbl2.Val2) As Val2
  , Concat(Tbl1.Val3,'/',Tbl2.Val3) As Val3
From Tbl1
    Cross Join Tbl2
```

[SQL Fiddle version.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6f39/13)

Comment: @ArunKillu - Absolute yes MySQL supports the Cross Join syntax and the use of comma delimited tables for cross joins should not be used.

Comment: ok thats correct join and cross joins are equivalent..in mysql

Comment: @ArunKillu - It all comes down to clarity of intent. The use of `Cross Join` makes it clear that is what I intended. If you just use `Join`, the presumption will be that you intended an inner join and overlooked adding the `On` clause even though that is valid MySQL syntax.